# May we have multiple deploys in ASP.NET MVC without loosing any request on website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I know that in PHP we may have multiple (+300) deploys in website without loosing requests on website.

Can we have the same number in ASP.NET MVC? for updating website features and sections?

Answer (score 0):

The deployment usually does is to just replace the whole file folder of the application. So this will create some request issue when copying the files.

The most reliable you are looking for should be a load-balanced environment, where you take down one server and deploy it then make it online, and take care of the other server as well.

Comment: Some PHP-based websites say that they have more than 300 deployments every day. Can we say that this is an advantage of PHP over ASP.NET (MVC)?